# Posted data missing using firebase

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to insert some data into my firebase but encountered the following error, the 2nd data is missing. Here are the code:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                //Creating firebase object
                Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

                //Getting values to store
                String name = mName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = mAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                String latlng = mLatLng.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating Person object
                FM_Spots spots = new FM_Spots();

                //Adding values
                spots.setName(name);
                spots.setAddress(address);
                spots.setLatLng(latlng);

                //Storing values to firebase
                //ref.child("FM_Spots").setValue(spots);
                Firebase newRef = ref.child("FM_Spots").push();
                newRef.setValue(spots);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I only have 2 fields which are name and the address is having data from the last field (latlng). Please advise, thank you.

-sea-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said "2nd data" you meant that the second field of the writable object is missing, right?

If so, you can use updateChildren(Map map) method instead of setValue() to specify fields you want to write directly:

```
newRef.updateChildren(convertFMSpotsToMap(spots));
```

where convertFMSpotsToMap() is something like this:

```
private static Map<String, Object> convertFMSpotsToMap(@NonNull FM_Spots spots) {
   HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("name", spots.getName());
   map.put("address", spots.getAddress());

   return map;
}
```